# The javascript dom prevents the form from making a post request

Tags: javascript, php, post, dom

I have run into an issue. This js dom prevents me from submitting the form. That is POST request is not being made. Can you guys help me out? I have posted the link to my code herewith.

[This is the link containing the form and respected js](https://codepen.io/shooriya-sridharan/pen/dyMJMwM)

I need the POST request to run so I could send the mail of confirmation to the user. That works fine without js DOM interrupting it. I tried `form.submit()` in the method, but it wasn't of any use. I'd be grateful if you guys could help me out.

Comment: What if you return a boolean from checkInputs()?  Namely:    if(!checkInputs()) e.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me.